# "Fault tolerant" number guessing

Tags: recreational-mathematics

Alice has a hidden random integer $a$ in range $[1, 2^n]$. Each time, Bob can guess a number $x$, and Alice will answer whether $x \ge a$ or $x < a$. However, Alice can give a wrong answer for **at most** 1 times. In the worst case, how many guesses does Bob need to surely find out $a$?

The best result I could get is about $n + 2\sqrt{n}$. Are there any better solutions?

Comment: Please add details about your solution, so others don't waste time re-creating it. Maybe hide it under a "spoiler", as this is tagged "recreational math"?

Comment: https://www.jstor.org/stable/2689593 (copy here: https://www.maa.org/programs/faculty-and-departments/classroom-capsules-and-notes/guess-a-number-with-lying)

Comment: Also worth a look: [Searching games with errors—fifty years of coping with liars](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304397501003036), by Andrzej Pelc. Some similar question on the SE network: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/32269/guess-a-number-with-at-most-one-wrong-answer https://mathoverflow.net/questions/308503/number-guessing-game-with-lying-oracle https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5680581/guess-the-number-with-lying-allowed Interesting problem, with ramifications in applied CS (error correcting codes, searching data with errors...)

Comment: Some basic information considerations indicates a lower bound of $n + \log_2 n + 1$, $n$ to get the $n$ bits of $a$ with the possible lie + $\log_2 n + 1$ to get location of the bit where she lied ($0$ if she didn't, $1$ to $n$, if she did).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the comments! It seems that I can't mark a comment as answer, so I have to post one.

---

This problem has been solved previously.

If one can ask a general yes-no question (whether or not $a \in S$), the answer is the smallest integer k that satisfies $2^{k-n} \ge k+1$. Therefore, $k \approx n + \log_2{n}$. The proof can be found [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0097316587900653).

[This paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022000080900148) shows that when only comparisons are allowed, the answer $k' \le k+1$. However, I haven't found out how to obtain an exact answer.

Comment: So my lower bound (with a small correction) was actually achievable. Good to know.

Comment: Actually, Andrzej Pelc's question is slightly different than yours. He allows Bob to ask any yes-no question, in particular "Is $a \in T$?" for any set $T$, Your version only allows $T$ to be unbounded intervals. So the answer to your problem may be higher (though apparently not much).

Comment: Thanks for finding that out. I've updated my answer.